# Sorting matrices by their norms

Tags: list-manipulation, sorting

I have a matrices A and their Norms(Matrices B).  I want to rank Matrices A based on their Norms. From smallest to highest Norm

Comment: The problem is, some of them have the same Norms

Comment: Okay, and what do you want to happen in that case? Do you want the original order to be preserved (*stable* sorting), or are you fine with them coming out in a random order, or do you have additional sorting criteria?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make a list of your matrices, called `myMatrices`, and then:

```
SortBy[myMatrices, -Norm[#]&]
```

or

```
Reverse@SortBy[myMatrices, Norm]
```

Comment: This clearly works and looks like the appropriate solution.  Is there some special interpretation of the syntax `-Norm` in this case?  I've not seen it documented anywhere.

Comment: @mikado  Check the syntax on `SortBy` and its examples.  Sorting by `Norm` gives ascending order, `-Norm` by descending, which is what you requested.

Comment: I can't see any documentation suggesting that `-Norm` is equivalent to `-Norm[#]&`, which it appears to be in this case.  I've looked at the help for `SortBy` in Mathematica 10 and can't see a mention of this.  Apologies if I've not looked carefully enough, but I would appreciate a specific reference.

Comment: Yes... `-Norm[#]&` is appropriate for your case.

Comment: Thank you. SortBy[myMatrices, Norm[#]&] works perfectly

Comment: One can also compose `-Norm[#]&` as `Minus @* Norm` (without mentioning arguments in any way) nowadays, although it's maybe more show-off than anything else.